# ActiveMQ Broker url on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, activemq-classic, kubectl

I have deployed my ActiveMQ on Kubernetes, but how to configure the broker to connect queue using port 61616? If I use the POD IP then it will not be static IP and every time pod recreate will create new IP. Is there anyway to get static IP or using ingress can we setup broker on port 61616?

Comment: There should be a matching Service, which will have a known DNS name; use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is a Community Wiki answer so feel free to edit it and add any additional details you consider important.*

For exposing any of your microservices in kubernetes either externally or internally you have a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

As [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) already stated in his comment:

> There should be a matching Service, which will have a known DNS name;
> use that. – David Maze yesterday

You don't need to worry about static IP. `Services` have also dynamic IPs assigned but they provide a reliable way to access your backend `Pods` via stable DNS name. Take a look also at [this section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) in the official docks.

In your case its enough to create a simple [`ClusterIP` `Service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) (which is the default `Service` type). It may look as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 61616
      targetPort: 61616
```

provided your app is listening on TCP port `61616` and you want your `Service` to expose the same port (`port`) as your `Pods` (`targetPort`).